# How to identify broken symlinks?

Tags: icons, shortcuts, symbolic-link

I have more than 1000 icons in a single directory and also there are hundreds of shortcuts (symbolic links?) inside that directory with different names, some of symbolic links are broken, i need to find which symbolic links are broken.

i tried using `ls -l` but it is difficult to use.

How do i do that? And is it possible to fix broken symbolic links. Thanks

Comment: I think by "shortcut" and "link", you mean symbolic links ("symlinks"), right? There are also hard links.

Comment: If yes, could you edit the remaining occurences of "shortcuts"? I changed some already to make it more clear - but it felt somewhat rough to change them all without an answer ;)

Comment: yes you are right sir,those are symbolic links.

Comment: Try `find . -xtype l` if you like - I had it in an answer, if it works for you, I'll restore that answer.

Comment: @Volker Siegel yes Great catch! Indeed, find `-xtype l` is enough.  `find -xtype l` should be faster. But I guess this would make a difference only on a large file system trees. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will list you all broken links:
    `find . -type l -exec sh -c "file -b {} | grep -q ^broken" \; -print`

Comment: wow, thank you sir, now i can solve my problem, thanks

Comment: To make it work on more than one **language**, it needs something like `LANG=C`, I think between the pipe and grep.

Answer (score -1):

It should work with the `find` option `-xtype`
(note the `x` - not the more common option `-type`):

`find . -xtype l`

The option is pretty obscure - so obscure that I don't dare to summarize it here. See `man find` if adventurous.

Comment: This would list all links not just the broken ones.

Comment: No, I did test at least that far... There are really many possible cases though... (Even ignoring symlinks to symlinks to broken symlinks...) I'll add some testscases/examples.